# How to optimally render Radios and bind changing values with React and JSX?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, radio-button, jsx

I've a state like this

```
const [inputMode, setInputMode] = useState(1);
```

This is what I'm doing to render and bind value to the state.

```
const renderRadios = () => 
{
    if (inputMode == 1) 
    {
        return (
            <>
               <input defaultChecked type="radio" value="1" onClick={e => setInputMode(parseInt(e.target.value))} />                   
               <input type="radio" value="2" onClick={e => setInputMode(parseInt(e.target.value))} />
            </>
        );
    }
    else if (inputMode == 2) 
    {
        return (
            <>
               <input type="radio" value="1" onClick={e => setInputMode(parseInt(e.target.value))} />                   
               <input defaultChecked type="radio" value="2" onClick={e => setInputMode(parseInt(e.target.value))} />
            </>
        );
    }
}

return(
    <h1>Result</h2>
    {renderRadios()}
);
```

Is there any alternate much simpler approach? I prefer

- Inline rendering within return statement, rather than using a separate arrow function to render radios *using multiple if-else ladders (Any way to inline it?)
- Is onClick binding correct to set value to the state? I tried
  onChange but it's not working somehow
- This works fine for me but I'm searching for a performant optimized version of the code.
- Here, I'm setting defaultChecked based on if-else cases, What is the best way to inline this and shrink code?

Comment: `InputMode` is `inputMode`?

Comment: Yes it's a typo. Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you really need to do is make the value of the `defaultChecked` prop truthy or falsey, depending on the state.

`onChange` works just fine, and since you already know the value of the inputs will be 1 or 2, you can use those directly instead of going through `parseInt(event.target.value)`.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Result</h1>
      <input defaultChecked={inputMode === 1} className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inputMode" value="1" id="tapanddone" onChange={e => setInputMode(1)} />
      <input defaultChecked={inputMode === 2} className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inputMode" value="2" id="logvalue" onChange={e => setInputMode(2)} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Live demo:

```js
function App() {
  const [inputMode, setInputMode] = React.useState(1);
  console.log('inputMode', inputMode);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Result</h1>
      <input defaultChecked={inputMode === 1} className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inputMode" value="1" id="tapanddone" onChange={e => setInputMode(Number(e.target.value))} />
      <input defaultChecked={inputMode === 2} className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inputMode" value="2" id="logvalue" onChange={e => setInputMode(Number(e.target.value))} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

> (Any way to inline it?)

If you couldn't use the above approach, yes, eg:

```
return (
  <h1>Result</h2>
  {
    inputMode === 1
    ? (
      <>
        <input> ...
      </>
    ) : (
      <>
        <input> ...
      </>
    )
  }
);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks mate